# How to check if hdfs is running?

Tags: hadoop

I would like to see if the hdfs file system for Hadoop is working properly. I know that `jps` lists the daemons that are running, but I don't actually know which daemons to look for.

I ran the following commands:
`$HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode`

`$HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode`

`$HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start resourcemanager`

`$HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start nodemanager`

Only namenode, resourcemanager, and nodemanager appeared when I entered `jps`.

Which daemons are supposed to be running in order for hdfs/Hadoop to function? Also, what could you do to fix hdfs if it is not running?

Comment: if you are not sure whether its running or not and do not remember which daemons correspond to the hdfs, you can check what the `hadoop dfs -ls /` command outputs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use any of the following approaches for to check your deamons status

1. JPS command would list all active deamons
2. the below is the most appropriate

   ```
      hadoop dfsadmin -report
   ```

   This would list down details of datanodes which is basically in a sense your HDFS
3. cat any file available in hdfs path.

Comment: What do you mean by "cat"?

Comment: sudo -u hdfs hadoop dfsadmin -report  , this should be done like this for comprehensive report.

Comment: hadoop dfsadmin -report is deprecated, one should use "hdfs dfsadmin -report" instead

Answer (score 4):

So, I spent two weeks validating my setup (it was fine) , finally found this command:

```
sudo -u hdfs jps
```

Initially my simple JPS command was showing only one process, but Hadoop 2.6 under Ubuntu LTS 14.04 was up.  I was using 'Sudo' to run the startup scripts.

Here is the startup that work with JPS listing multiple processes:

```
sudo su hduser
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-yarn.sh
```